# How can I keep a cell selected while scrolling the tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want a cell to remain selected when it is touched and if it is touched again to be deselected. This is my code which is not working:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if let value = selectedCell?.selected.boolValue {
        if !value {
            print("cell was selected and will remain selected") 
            selectedCell?.selected = true
        } else {
            print("cell is deselected")
            selectedCell?.selected = false
        }
    }
}
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: You would need to save the cell state in an array, and then use it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath to differentiate which cell should be selected and which not.

Comment: And how to deselect the selected on after. Right now I just want to make it work for one cell. But the array idea will be necessary as I have a whole menu I am implementing to work with this feature

Comment: You need to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didDeselectRowAtIndexPath,

Comment: Before this create an array which will have equal number of objects to cells. Add @"NO" strings in the array for all objects. Then is the in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath simply do arrayCellState replaceObjectAtIndexPath: indexPath.row withObject: @"YES" and vice versa in the didDeselectRowAtIndexPath. And then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath check the selected cell as if([[arrayCellState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString: @"YES"]) , if yes cell.setSelected = YES; and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Remember rules:

- Store cells data in model
- UITableViewController only for visualisation

On your code, make storing selected value, for example in array, by `indexPath.row`

Comment: Yes I know, but I just want to indicate visually that option was indeed saved in the data model. I don't want to use accessory type to implement that due to some design constraints

Comment: @irkinosor you don't need to use accessory type for it. You can just redraw background of cell if it was selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default tag value of each cell in `cellForRowAtIndex` as `cell.tag = 0`

Inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function you can do something like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
   if selectedCell.tag == 0 {
       print("cell was selected")
       selectedCell.tag = 1
   }
   else {
       print("cell was deselected")
       selectedCell.tag = 0
   }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the table load from cellForRowAtIndexPath with no cell selected.

Comment: Thanks mate, but no it doesn't. Appreciate the effort!

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I added my solution. Check it how

Comment: Cool! May the Force be with you.

Answer (score 0):

if all you ever have is one selected row at a time, then even without a data model (which you should have), you could have an attribute of the ViewController `selectedRowIndex` which is updated each time you select a row, and refresh the tableView -  as part of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can check if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex and make whatever visual changes you need

define an attribute to track the currently selected row

```
var selectedRowIndex = -1
```

then update that attribute when the user selects a row

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    // build up an array of rows to be refreshed
    // the previously selected row (if any)
    // and the current one
    var indexPaths : [NSIndexPath] = []

    // if a row was previous selected, clear the display
    if selectedRowIndex != -1
    {
        indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedRowIndex, inSection: 0))
    }

    selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
    indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedRowIndex, inSection: 0))

    // now refresh just those rows
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

}
```

and then do something with it when the row is redrawn

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell

    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
      // everything else
    return cell
}
```

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath get to only be call once right? when the table load for the first time. But I want this highlight / unhighlight to happen interactively like it would work for accessory type checmark

Comment: Do the checkmark adjustments in the `willDisplayCell` function instead of in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thanks Rusell, but I am afraid you didn;t understood my problem properly. and remember cellForRowAtindexPath get to be call only at the beginning. And I want cell to be highlighted /unhighlighted imediately as the user tap on the cell

Comment: try it - `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` will force a redraw of the row you have just selected, and of the one that was previously selected, and `cellForRowAtindexPath` will be re-called.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused, I meant change the color, instead of the  checkmark.  Have you tried using `willDisplayCell` ?

Comment: I posted my solution. Thanks guys for the contribution

Answer (score 0):

alright, this is how I manage to do it declaring a `var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?` and then in the didSelectRowAtindexPath did the following:

```
            if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
                tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
                selectedIndexPath = nil
            }else{
                tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)
                selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that cell selection and deselection is handled by default - you shouldn't have to mess with the selected values of the cells yourself!

You may need to update some elements of the cell in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method based on the selected state.

If this isn't working out of the box and/or you want to customise this behaviour, you should look at the `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` method as well. The combination of these two methods should allow you to control the selected state completely.